# How to show doc, docx files on android by any library?

Tags: java, android, ms-office

I am trying to show doc, docx files in android serveral times, but I cannot know how to do.
I have searched through the internet and found some libraries such as POI, docx4j, aspose and so on. But I don't know what to use for my app.
Who can give me the whole android sample project to show doc files.
Best regards

Answer (score 2):

If you want to preview your word(**.doc**/**.docx**) document I would suggest you to use Groupdocs.Viewer [Groupdocs](http://www.groupdocs.com). They provide [libraries](http://www.groupdocs.com/java/total-library) for java. Also you can find proper documentation in this [link](http://www.groupdocs.com/docs/display/viewerjava/Developer+Guide).

Comment: Groupdocs is not free. Though it's great, I cannot. thanks. By the way, is it possible to be free when I only preview only doc&docx files?

Answer (score -1):

One can use [MuPDF](https://mupdf.com/index.html) for viewing almost all type of documents such as pdf,.doc,ppt,xls,etc natively. Its quite fast, and they also have a open source version for non-commercial use.
Find the [Documentation](https://mupdf.com/docs/appkit/api/2.1.0/android-getting-started.html) here.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31431710)